# Simulating JMS - jUnit

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, jms, integration-testing

I need to simulate JMS behavior while performing automated tests via maven/hudson. I was thinking about using some mock framework i.e. Mockito to achieve that goal but maybe there is some easier tool which can accomplish this task? I have read a little bit about ActiveMQ but from what I have found out it requires to install broker prior using it. In my case it is important to have everything run by maven only because I don't have any privileges to install anything on the build server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run ActiveMQ in embedded mode - the broker starts within your application and queues are created on the fly. You just need to add `activemq.jar` and run few lines of code.

On the other hand there is a [Mockrunner](http://mockrunner.sourceforge.net/examplesjms.html) library that has support for JMS - although it was designed mainly for unit tests, not integration.