# Test case for ActiveMQ

Tags: testing, jakarta-ee, junit, jms, activemq-classic

I was wondering how to test JMS using ActiveMQ based on the answer suggesting using ActiveMQ to do the test [Simulating JMS - jUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217315/simultating-jms-junit)

However, I am not getting the message I was expecting from the MessageConsumer.  If I used receive it just hangs there.

Here is my code

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JmsTest {
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
            "vm://localhost?broker.persistent=true");
    final Queue queue;
    final Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    final Session session = connection.createSession(true,
            Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    {
        queue = session.createQueue("test");
    }
    {
        final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        final TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("testing");
        producer.send(message);
    }
    {
        final MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        final TextMessage message = (TextMessage) consumer.receiveNoWait();
        // "message" is null at this point
        Assert.assertEquals("testing", message.getText());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Tim, we found it at about the same time, but I had to make a few other modifications as I have specified in my comment.   In a nutshell, I have to make sure the "transactional" attribute is "false" and as Tim had noted I had to do a connection.start() call.

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
            "vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");

    final Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    final Session session = connection.createSession(false,
            Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    final Queue queue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
    {
        final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        final TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("testing");
        producer.send(message);
    }
    {
        final MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        final TextMessage message = (TextMessage) consumer.receiveNoWait();
        Assert.assertNotNull(message);
        Assert.assertEquals("testing", message.getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Before you can receive a message you need to call connection.start() otherwise no messages will be dispatched to the consumer.  Also your code should not assume that receiveNoWait will always return a message, since it can take a small amount of time for a message to be dequeued and routed to the consumer, so attempting a retry there or using the timed receive() called might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Using Topics would look something like this:

```
        final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        final javax.jms.Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.setClientID("12345");
        connection.start();

        final Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        final Topic temporaryTopic = session.createTemporaryTopic();

        final MessageConsumer consumer1 = session.createConsumer(temporaryTopic);

        final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(temporaryTopic);
        producer.send(session.createTextMessage("Testmessage"));

        final TextMessage message = (TextMessage)consumer1.receiveNoWait();


        Assert.assertNotNull(message);
        Assert.assertEquals("testing", message.getText());
```

Comment: As @tim-bish said, connection.start() needs to be called before it's used.

Comment: consumer needs to be created before a producer sends a message.